# How to have a data object manage its own state in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I decided to organize my Vue application by having a set of classes that encapsulate the data, maintain their own state (edited, deleted, etc) and know how to sync their state with the back-end system. Maybe this was a bad choice, because it plays very badly with Vue as follows.

This is an extremely simplified version of what I am doing, that illustrates the problem with the minimum of code.

## First Attempt

Assume that I have an object that encapsulates the data as follows:

ModelState.ts

```js
export public enum ModelState { saved, modified, deleted, new }
```

NameModel.ts

```js
export public class NameModel {
  public name: string = 'New name'
  public state: ModelState = ModelState.modified

  public save(): Promise<boolean> {
    this.state = ModelState.saved
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

And I want to display this in a Vue component like this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { NameModel } from 'NameModel'
import { ModelState } from 'ModelState'

export interface MyComponentProps{
  nameModel: NameModel
}
const props = defineProps<MyComponentProps>();

function saveClicked() {
  props.nameModel.save()
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="nameModel.name">
    <button 
      v-if="nameModel.state == ModelState.modified" 
      @click="saveClicked()">Save</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

This will correctly allow the name propertyto edited, and the Save button will be displayed, but clicking on the Save button will not make the Save button disappear. This is because passing a `NameModel` as a prop will wrap it in a reactive proxy. The proxy is deeply reactive, but only when accessing the properties via the proxy.

When the save button is clicked, the `NameModel` does update its `state` property, but this property is not reactive unless it is mutated via the prop, and therefore the UI does not reflect the change of state.

## Second Attempt

I thought I could fix the problem by explicitly making the `state` property reactive, so I modified my `NameModel` class like this:

NameModel.ts

```js
import { ref, type Ref } from 'vue'
export public class NameModel {
  public name: string = 'New name'
  public state: Ref<ModelState> = ref(ModelState.modified)

  public save(): Promise<boolean> {
    this.state.value = ModelState.saved
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

This passes all the unit tests and appears to be correct, but at runtime is throws an exception saying that object does not have a `value` property. This is odd, because I am using strict mode on typescript, and it should not be possible to get a type mismatch at runtime like this.

The reason that this doesn't work, is that when Vue makes an object reactive, it "unwraps" reactive properties, essentially modifying my object's `state` property from `Ref<ModelState>` to `ModelState`. This runtime modification of the type is pretty unpleasant behavior by Vue IMHO.

## Third Attempt

To get this working, I moved the state management logic out of the data model and into the component. This works, but I think is a very poor separation of concerns, and also means that I need to repeat this logic in each component that mutates the state.

The revised code looks like this:

```js
export public class NameModel {
  public name: string = 'New name'
  public state: ModelState = ModelState.modified

  public save(): Promise<boolean> {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { NameModel } from 'NameModel'
import { ModelState } from 'ModelState'

export interface MyComponentProps{
  nameModel: NameModel
}
const props = defineProps<MyComponentProps>();

function saveClicked() {
  props.nameModel.save().then((success) => {
    if (success) props.nameModel.state = ModelState.saved
  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="nameModel.name">
    <button 
      v-if="nameModel.state == ModelState.modified" 
      @click="saveClicked()">Save</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Which works, but feels inadequate. What is the better way of doing this?

## Additional Context

In my actual solution the code is much more sophisticated than this minimal demonstration.

I have a Vue component with slots for the view, edit, delete and new user experiences. This component now has the state management logic in it, even though it can be used with any data model that inherits from a `PersistedEditable` base class.

This is not great, because data models have slightly different behaviors (maybe cannot delete if they have child records, or permissions may be required etc).

I am also planning to have a web socket inform the front end when data changes on the back end, and the logical place to update the state is in the data model, not the Vue component, but this won't work, because the data model cannot update its own state.

## Motivation (EDIT)

For more clarity, I am editing my question to include something about why I want to do this.

I love the way that Vue manages UI state in a reactive way, and loved working with Vue in its early days. I am coming back to Vue now because I enjoyed working with it so much, and absolutely want to have it manage the state of my UI.

However I want to keep the logic for managing the state of the data separate from the logic to manage the UI state. To understand why, consider a scenario in which I have a piece of data that is displayed in different ways in various parts of the UI, and I receive a web socket message telling my application that another user deleted this data. In this case I want all components that are displaying this data to render it in its deleted representation.

The reactive features of Vue will of course propagate the change in state to the UI, but who mutates the state in response to the web socket message? I can't duplicate this logic in all components that display this kind of data. It would be ideal if the data model was able to update it's own state.

## Playgrounds (EDIT)

[First attempt - not reactive](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpdUcFuhCAQ/ZUpFzW1q3tddZPeeumtSS9cjGKXRoEImCbGf+8wNkqaEALvvXnMG1b2asxl8YLdWG27WRoHVjhv7lwByMno2cEKsxhy3NrOyUXABsOsJ0iwLIlkTk7iXfdi/KMvxYFcvi0qg7bTyjqYSNYclumhzCooCrBy8mPrROTZWmjBzNpELvaLPIY0eRPjqOFTz2P/lGRc1cUeBmPgxYnJBDsKVT+u93Wl4m2rC7wR2suFYGo3PEtsQImWyngHywvxDWdYzhlSdRGZs5zFkXGm8QT/zW3PcAZsYA0vBeAGZR7O3vRo/EHI4BWOSitIM9Kh8iHt3mkTnZ/hWu08/mMo1d6lRJ9uOVzLssxIt3GFi6uz8VOXBglX4odC9GJo/Ri1XLHtF04axhE=)

[Second attempt - runtime error due to unwrapping](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpdkUFvhCAQhf/KlIuaWnWvu+4mvfXSW5NeuJgVuzQIRMA0Mf73DrMbJZsYA28+HvOGhb1bW81BsCNr3XWS1oMTPtgL1wBytGbysMAkhhJ/3dXLWcAKw2RGyPBYlmBejuLT9EI9ylW9KdWvQzKyV6Odh5Gw82aZb2RxgroGJ8egOi8Sz85BB3YyNnFxP+Qx5NmHUMrAt5lU/5IVXLf1PQzGwI0Xo412FKq9HS7LQofXta1xR2ov5yjvLccVEbFCiNQ2eJjfqPszZ2jBGZbaOrmAlSyNjXNNp/g0u3uOPeQZlnhTFI4UrCnKKATbo/sXyUPQODOjIS8IRvwmHbVbzZ0KAl2elVc4nO4sPm60McHnBO3OJRyapimIW7nGj+s9yc7lEeFa/FGqXgxdUEmGE1v/ATAhzcQ=)

[Third attempt - works but logic feels misplaced](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpNUbluhDAQ/ZWJG0DZcLQLrJQuTbpIaWgQmMQRPuQDRUL8+44NAjeW5l2eYyXvSuWLo+ROGjNopiwYap16dAKAcSW1hRU0nW749INlC4UNJi05JGhLOnGILOP0U450Psi8OJH8z6AOoBODFMYCD7L2DExPZVZDUYBh3M29pYewN9CD0lLFGU6NqPhCIwZNTmCQFJBmqxcFX+5TkYyKV6hqz+OE3imdTa+cG1RlWWYo2PaPLir1aNS/+QndT2nyQedZwrfU8/iSZJ1oin2JuD4sLOXKDxKW2fxWj3UN5m1rCqwCOrIlwFeXnvVooJlQzsLyFvi2I2jvCFJNEYWTG4mXjbfcG71u0kJYjAfuUIYR6X+420in3s2RtibbE8QpuDw=)

[Composable - suggested by @TheHiggsBroson](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpVUk1rhTAQ/CvbXPRR68e1T4Xeeumt0IsX0dhaYhJiIgXxv3ez+jCCCtmZ2Z3ZuLI3rdPFcfbKyrkzo7Ywc+t03UiAcdLKWFjB8CHBT9vZceGwwWDUBBHKooDmZv45TvxD9VwcjDSzj0r6OyPZ0zslZwsT0aqLKr7dA8L8jTBOjqN3LoSCL2VE/xTdGllmu1U0iQfLJy1ay8ly+VPU60ribSszPFG1HxcqkxPviVBfJXiU2llYXgivGobyhiFUZkFzlrAwDW4s3M9lKxijkXuMy1YqiG9Q1bCeMcnMnjPf45+Y0z2O9nJkDE7i+pXEDiQHkqZLK5yHg8MzFNQI/FV6tXI2PnslUOT5MWt7DDzh4xL8a/BPMDIcd2jwaST/o/Q9H1onrkHvbPsHVs7LSw==)

[Renderless component - I think this is what @TheHiggsBroson suggested](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNptUcFOwzAM/RWTSzsx1u66dZO4cQCJAxIHymFq0xKUJlGTTEhV/53Y2bpucLTf8/Pz88AejVkdPWcbVtiqF8aB5c6bfakARGd072CAnjcwQtPrDpJATrYz1ImOv+iayxO+yqbO6tteUd/OwLNuRTXxr9voBqdwrtLKOuhIfYcu0kl7QcIngm1PcPLEpdTwrntZ3yWLUhVZvCrcEwrHOyMPjtN1xY2dzaS9KxntLBlkkfq13g8D7RnHIgsVdWtxpDbditOEYpdgoYx3cHwgHDVtW7IAFdnMB1uyeV7hD/yHwqp5c/AypI9aSNlAXqpxGwb+Bnb7PpAH1YaVztLGc1Cm18aGqIK2UPwVq/QjmfYnnyGxC9ubOnjEZWGk8apyQqt0ER1BFKOzo3kKYPd/+x7W9C9Ae6iovUsv+ktY53keXzpGCxcwxf7sj2z8BaGn7aI=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, this is a very interesting concept. I don't know off the top of my head if there's a way you could achieve this outside of integrating with some Vue functionality. I don't want to be the typical Stack Overflow, "THAT'S NOT HOW YOU DO IT," guy but I think I am understanding the motivation behind your approach here and I have a couple of ways you might be able to address those concerns.

Forgive if me if I'm reading too much into your code, but it seems to me that what you're aiming to accomplish with these classes is a separation of state logic from the component. In other words, you'd like to package units of your data into a piece of code that is separate from your display logic (i.e. the component itself.)

Assuming that is correct, I have good news for you. Although I am not aware of any method to utilize the vanilla `class` operator to achieve this, you have a couple of options, each with their pros and cons:

#### Pinia

[Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) is "type safe, extensible, and modular by design," in much the same way a class would be. You can use it to contain state as well as methods in the same way a class could. Similar to a component, you can either represent them with the [options API](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#usage-with-the-options-api) (everything structured in an object) or with the [composition API](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/composing-stores.html#composing-stores) (everything structured as a function).

They vary from classes in that one of the explicit goals of Pinia is to manage the *same* state in each place you are utilizing the store. In other words, instantiating the store in two places of your code will point you to the same state under the hood. Changing it in one place changes it in both places.

Benefits:

- Highly modular
- Highly portable

Drawbacks:

- Difficult/impractical to instantiate several instances of the same item.
- Difficult/impractical to use the instance of your store as a prop to a child component.
- Requires additional library (though it is officially maintained by Vue).

#### Composables

If you thought Pinia sounds like a great option until you realize all the "instances" point to the same data under the hood, then maybe you'll prefer [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#composables) with the Vue3 Composition API. It allows you to do largely the same thing as a Pinia store, the key difference being that each instantiation points to its own, distinct memory. An adaption of the code in your example might look like this:

```
// useNameModel.ts
export const useNameModel = () => {
  const name = ref<string>('New name');
  const state = ref<ModelState>(ModelState.modified);

  const save(): Promise<boolean> {
    state.value = ModelState.saved;
  };

  return {
    name,
    state,
    save,
  };
};
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { NameModel } from 'NameModel'
import { ModelState } from 'ModelState'
import { useNameModel } from '@/composables/useNameModel.ts'


const nameModel = useNameModel();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="nameModel.name">
    <button 
      v-if="nameModel.state == ModelState.modified" 
      @click="nameModel.save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

If you wanted, you could instantiate `nameModel` in the parent component and pass it in as a prop. Then, when you call `props.nameModel.save()`, it will update the state within the instance you created in the parent component. Very helpful. This becomes very powerful when you combine it with Vue3's [inject and provide](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#provide-inject) paradigm. This allows you to instantiate your composable and then `provide` it which will make it available to any descendant in your component tree who can then `inject` it. So here you get the best of both worlds. Strictly speaking, you could use a provided instance of a composable to achieve the same result as Pinia, but in practice there are some things that Pinia makes more performant than the `provide/inject` method.

Benefits:

- Highly modular
- Several instances control their own states
- Individual instances can be passed between components either via `props` or `inject/provide`.

Drawbacks:

- Difficult-ish to extend as it is function based.

#### Renderless components

Finally, you could use a renderless component. I wanted to include three options for you, I'm kind of reaching with this suggestion tbh, but essentially you can use it to store all of your state and then expose that state via a slot or something if you wanted. I would never structure it like this, but *you could*. Sometimes it is very helpful, but it's always implementation specific. I would need to know more about your codebase before I ever suggested this approach over the other two.

Maybe you could put side-effects into a renderless component? Even then though it would probably be more practical to use a composable. Maybe somebody else will be willing to chime in on this.

Benefits:

- Very creative? (:

Drawbacks:

- Basically the same as a composable but without the flexibility to pass the state around as easily.

I hope this all helps. Sorry I couldn't help you figure out how to do it exactly the way you were envisioning.

**EDIT**

#### Proxy Class

I did some research and read that using Proxy objects could be an option. It creates a wrapper around an object and allows interception of fundamental operations like setting and getting properties. It could be an alternative to Pinia if you don't want to include a state management library in your project. Here is how you could implement it in your class:

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue';

export class NameModel {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      set: function (target, prop, value) {
        target[prop] = value;
        if (prop === 'state' && value === ModelState.saved) {
          target.save();
        }
        return true;
      },
    });
  }
  
  public name: string = 'New name';
  public state: ModelState = ModelState.modified;

  public save(): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('saving');
    this.state = ModelState.saved;
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

That would be the closest solution to your current approach I think.

Comment: That was super helpful. Thank you for taking the time. On first reading it looks like composables might be my next iteration. I will let you know how this turns out.

Comment: BTW I am already using Pinia to store the raw data that is retrieved from the back-end, and global things like the logged in user, so I could extend my use of it to this.

Comment: Sure thing! I love Vue. It occurred to me reviewing your message that you may also like to try out Vue's [plugins](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#plugins) feature

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this thread and wanting to follow the same approach as me, this is my solution. I am crediting @TheHiggsBroson with the correct answer, because their answer gave me the clues I needed to get in the right path.

## Editable

The most important part of this solution is my `Editable.ts` file (below). It defines `type Editable<Data> = {...} & Data` which makes `EditableData` an extension of any type `Data`, adding a set of properties and methods that manage the state of the editable.

The reactivity is achieved by defining a function that constructs a new `reactive(Editable<Data>)` and returns it, but maintains a reference. This function then adds methods to `Editable<Data>` that reference the reactive proxy for the editable, making all of its mutations to the editable reactive.

The important parts of the `newEditable` function looks like this (see below for full source code):

```js
type Editable<Data> = {
  state: string
  cancel(): void
} & Data

const newEditable = function(data: Data): Editable<Data> {
  var editable: Editable<Data> = reactive({ ...data, state }) as Editable<Data>

  editable.cancel = () => {
    // Note change made on reactive proxy for editable
    // even though this cancel function is a method of Editable
    editable.state = 'cancelled'
  }
  
  return editable
}
```

## pinia stores

I store all of these `Editable<Data>` in pinia where I cache them, nd perform all of the back-end integration to retrieve, save, delete etc the objects to the database.

Each store handles a specific object type, and exports a use function, for example `usePerson(id?: string)` that returns an editable person wrapper for an existing record, or creates a new person record if the `id` is null.

If the editable person is not in pinia then the store retrieves the record from the back-end and calls `newEditable()` from above to make it editable.

## CrudPanel

Is a generic vue component that hosts view, edit, delete etc components in slots, and displays a set of buttons that are reactive to the current state of the `Editable<Data>` passed in as a prop, hiding or disabling buttons that don't apply in the current state, and switching slots to display the display, edit etc view of the record.

## PersonCrud

Is a vue component that contains a `CrudPanel` and simply fills the view, edit, delete etc slots with the relevant components for the type of record it is displaying. This is only 20 lines of code for each record type I want to edit.

## PersonEdit

Is an editor for a person record. I pass `Editable<Person>` as a prop, which is already reactive and maintains edit state. This is also 20-30 lines of code for each record type (for simple types).

## Source Code

This is the full source listing of a few files:

### Editable.ts

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export enum EditableState {
    New,
    Saved,
    Modified,
    Deleted
}

export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
export type PersistenceResult = Promise<Maybe<Error>>

export type EditableEvents = {
    onRefresh?(): PersistenceResult
    onSave?(): PersistenceResult
    onDelete?(): PersistenceResult
    onUndelete?(): PersistenceResult
}

export type Editable<Data> = {
    _backup: Data
    state: EditableState
    
    canRefresh: boolean
    canEdit: boolean
    canSave: boolean
    canCancel: boolean
    canDelete: boolean
    canUndelete: boolean

    setState(newState: EditableState): void

    backup(): void
    restore(): void

    refresh(): PersistenceResult

    edit(): PersistenceResult
    save(): PersistenceResult
    cancel(): PersistenceResult

    delete(): PersistenceResult
    undelete(): PersistenceResult

} & EditableEvents & Data

export const newEditable = function<Data>(data: Data, state: EditableState, events: EditableEvents): Editable<Data> {
    var editable: Editable<Data> = reactive({ ...data, ...events }) as Editable<Data>

    editable.backup = () => {
        var { 
            _backup,
            state,
            canRefresh,
            canEdit,
            canSave,
            canCancel,
            canDelete,
            canUndelete,
            setState,
            backup,
            restore,
            refresh,
            edit,
            save,
            cancel,
            delete: _delete,
            undelete,
            onRefresh,
            onSave,
            onDelete,
            onUndelete,
            ...data
        } = editable;
        editable._backup = data as Data
    }

    editable.restore = () => {
        if (editable._backup) {
            let key: keyof Data
            for (key in editable._backup as Data) editable[key] = editable._backup[key] as any
        }
    }

    editable.setState = (newState: EditableState) => {
        editable.canEdit = (newState == EditableState.Saved) && !!editable.onSave
        editable.canRefresh = (newState == EditableState.Saved) && !!editable.onRefresh
        editable.canSave = ((newState == EditableState.Modified) || (newState == EditableState.New)) && !!editable.onSave
        editable.canCancel = (newState == EditableState.Modified)
        editable.canDelete = ((newState == EditableState.Saved) || (newState == EditableState.Modified))  && !!editable.onDelete
        editable.canUndelete = (newState == EditableState.Deleted) && !!editable.onUndelete
        editable.state = newState
    }

    editable.edit = () => {
        editable.backup()
        editable.setState(EditableState.Modified)
        return Promise.resolve(null)
    }

    editable.refresh = () => {
        if (!editable.onRefresh) {
            return Promise.resolve(null)
        }

        return editable.onRefresh().then(result => {
            if (!result) editable.setState(EditableState.Saved)
            return Promise.resolve(result)
        })
    }

    editable.save = () => {
        if (!editable.onSave) {
            return Promise.resolve(null)
        }

        return editable.onSave().then(result => {
            if (!result) editable.setState(EditableState.Saved)
            return Promise.resolve(result)
        })
    }

    editable.cancel = () => {
        editable.restore()
        editable.setState(EditableState.Saved)
        return Promise.resolve(null)
    }

    editable.delete = () => {
        if (!editable.onDelete) {
            return Promise.resolve(null)
        }

        return editable.onDelete().then(result => {
            if (!result) editable.setState(EditableState.Deleted)
            return Promise.resolve(result)
        })
    }

    editable.undelete = () => {
        if (!editable.onUndelete) {
            return Promise.resolve(null)
        }

        return editable.onUndelete().then(result => {
            if (!result) editable.setState(EditableState.Saved)
            return Promise.resolve(result)
        })
    }

    editable.setState(state)
    return editable
}
```

### builders.ts

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import type { BuilderV1 } from '@/schema.js'
import { type Editable, type PersistenceResult, EditableState, newEditable } from './Editable'

export type Builder = Editable<BuilderV1>

type BuilderCache = {
  [key: string]: Builder
}

type BuildersStoreState = {
  builders: BuilderCache
}

export const useBuildersStore = defineStore('builders', {
  state: (): BuildersStoreState => ({
    builders: {}
  }),
  getters: {
    getBuilderById(state): (id: string) => Promise<Builder | undefined> {
      return (id: string) => {
        return Promise.resolve(state.builders[id]);
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    cache(builder: Builder) {
      this.builders[builder.id] = builder
    },
    invalidate(id: string) {
      delete this.builders[id];
    }
  }
})

let nextId = 1;

const newBuilderV1 = function(): BuilderV1 {
  return {
    id: (nextId++).toString(),
    name: '',
    createdAt: new Date().toUTCString(),
    updatedAt: new Date().toUTCString(),
    addressList: [],
    contactList: []
  }
}

export const useBuilder = (id?: string): Promise<Builder> => {
  let builder: Builder;

  const onRefresh = function (): PersistenceResult {
    // Fetch from back-end
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }

  const onSave = function (): PersistenceResult {
    // Save to back-end
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }

  const onDelete = function (): PersistenceResult {
    // Delete from back-end
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }

  const onUndelete = function (): PersistenceResult {
    // Un-delete from back-end
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }

  if (!id) {
    builder = newEditable(
      newBuilderV1(), 
      EditableState.New, 
      { onRefresh, onSave, onDelete, onUndelete });
    return Promise.resolve(builder)
  }

  const builders = useBuildersStore()
  return builders.getBuilderById(id).then(builder => {
    if (!builder) throw new Error(`Builder ${id} was not found`)
    return Promise.resolve(builder)
  });
}
```

### CrudPanel.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref, type Ref } from 'vue'
import { type Maybe, type Editable, EditableState } from '@/stores/Editable.js'

export interface CrudPanelProps {
  editable: Maybe<Editable<any>>
}
const props = defineProps<CrudPanelProps>();

const deleting: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);

const mode = computed(() => {
  if (deleting.value) return 'delete';
  if (props.editable) {
    switch (props.editable.state) {
      case EditableState.Modified:
        return 'edit'
      case EditableState.Deleted:
        return 'deleted'
      case EditableState.New:
        return 'new'
    }
  }
  return 'view'
})

function editClicked() {
  if (props.editable)
    props.editable.edit()
}

function refreshClicked() {
  if (props.editable)
    props.editable.refresh()
}

function cancelClicked() {
  if (deleting.value) {
    deleting.value = false
  } else {
    if (props.editable)
      props.editable.cancel()
  }
}

function saveClicked() {
  if (props.editable)
    props.editable.save()
}

function askDeleteClicked() {
  deleting.value = true
}

function deleteClicked() {
  if (props.editable)
    props.editable.delete().then((error: Maybe<Error>) => {
      if (!error) deleting.value = false
    })
}

function undeleteClicked() {
  if (props.editable)
    props.editable.undelete()
}

</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="editable">
    <div class="view" v-if="mode == 'view'">
      <slot name="view"></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="edit" v-if="mode == 'edit'">
      <slot name="edit"></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="new" v-if="mode == 'new'">
      <slot name="new"></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="delete" v-if="mode == 'delete'">
      <slot name="delete">
        <div>Are you sure that you want to delete "{{ editable.name }}"?</div>
      </slot>
    </div>
    <div class="deleted" v-if="mode == 'deleted'">
      <slot name="deleted">
        <div>Record deleted</div>
      </slot>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button v-if="editable.canSave && mode != 'delete'" @click="saveClicked()">Save</button>
      <button v-if="editable.canCancel || mode == 'delete'" @click="cancelClicked()">Cancel</button>
      <button v-if="editable.canDelete && mode == 'delete'" @click="deleteClicked()">Yes, delete it!</button>
      <button v-if="editable.canRefresh && mode != 'delete'" @click="refreshClicked()">Refresh</button>
      <button v-if="editable.canEdit && mode != 'delete'" @click="editClicked()">Edit</button>
      <button v-if="editable.canDelete && mode != 'delete'" @click="askDeleteClicked()">Delete</button>
      <button v-if="editable.canUndelete && mode != 'delete'" @click="undeleteClicked">Undelete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

### BuilderCrud.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  import CrudPanel from '../containers/CrudPanel.vue'
  import BuilderView from './BuilderView.vue'
  import BuilderEdit from './BuilderEdit.vue'
  import { type Builder } from '@/stores/builders.js'
  import { type Maybe } from '@/stores/Editable.js'

  export interface CrudPanelProps {
    builder: Maybe<Builder>
  }

  const props = defineProps<CrudPanelProps>();
</script>

<template>
  <CrudPanel :editable="builder">
    <template #view><BuilderView :builder="builder"></BuilderView></template>
    <template #edit><BuilderEdit :builder="builder"></BuilderEdit></template>
    <template #new><BuilderEdit :builder="builder"></BuilderEdit></template>
  </CrudPanel>
</template>
```

### BuilderEdit.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { computed } from 'vue'
  import { type Builder } from '@/stores/builders.js'
  import { type Maybe } from '@/stores/Editable.js'

  export interface BuilderEditProps {
    builder: Maybe<Builder>
  }

  const props = defineProps<BuilderEditProps>();

  const builderName = computed(() => {
    if (!props.builder) return '';
    return props.builder._backup ? props.builder._backup.name : props.builder.name
  })
</script>

<template>
  <div class="editor">
    <h1>Builder {{ builderName }}</h1>
    <div><span class="field-label">Name</span><input v-if="builder" v-model="builder.name"></div>
    <div><span class="field-label">Tax reference</span><input v-if="builder" v-model="builder.taxReference"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```